# Make zsh zle restore characters on backspace in vi overwrite-mode

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-zle

I am using Zsh in Vi-mode.

When `$KEYMAP == vicmd` (i.e. *command-mode*), I want hitting backspace to move the cursor to the left by one character, without deleting anything. **[working]**

When `$KEYMAP == viins && $ZLE_STATE == *insert*` (i.e. *insert-mode*), I want hitting backspace to move the cursor to the left by one character, deleting the immediately preceding character on the line. **[working]**

When `$KEYMAP == viins && $ZLE_STATE == *overwrite*` (i.e. *overwrite-mode* / *replace-mode*), I want hitting backspace to move the cursor to the left by one character, **restoring** the immediately preceding character on the line with the one that had originally been there prior to entering into *overwrite-mode*. **[NOT working]**

Here is an example:

```
# [COMMAND MODE] We start with the following string on the command line:
$ Hello, world!
     ^
     cursor position

# [REPLACE MODE] Now, I hit "R" to enter replace-mode and I type "stuff".
$ Helstufforld!
          ^
          cursor position

# [REPLACE MODE] Finally, I hit backspace 3 times.
$ Helst, world!
       ^
       cursor position
```

The above example shows what I want to happen when I hit backspace while in *overwrite-mode*; however, what really happens is the following:

```
# [COMMAND MODE] We start with the following string on the command line:
$ Hello, world!
     ^
     cursor position

# [REPLACE MODE] Now, I hit "R" to enter replace-mode and I type "stuff".
$ Helstufforld!
          ^
          cursor position

# [REPLACE MODE] Finally, I hit backspace 3 times.
$ Helstworld!
       ^
       cursor position
```

Notice how, when hitting backspace in the second example, rather than restoring the original 3 characters that were just overwritten (i.e. `", w"`), instead the last 3 characters that replaced these characters (i.e. `"uff"`) were deleted, and the characters to the right of the cursor were shifted to the left.

How do I get the behavior that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I ended up hacking together a solution to the problem I was having, which I will post here in case anyone else encounters the same issue.

#### Solution

Put this in your *.zshrc*:

```
readonly ZLE_VI_MODE_CMD=0
readonly ZLE_VI_MODE_INS=1
readonly ZLE_VI_MODE_REP=2
readonly ZLE_VI_MODE_OTH=3

function zle-vi-mode {
    if [[ $KEYMAP == vicmd ]]; then
        echo -n $ZLE_VI_MODE_CMD
    elif [[ $KEYMAP == (viins|main) ]] && [[ $ZLE_STATE == *insert* ]]; then
        echo -n $ZLE_VI_MODE_INS
    elif [[ $KEYMAP == (viins|main) ]] && [[ $ZLE_STATE == *overwrite* ]]; then
        echo -n $ZLE_VI_MODE_REP
    else
        echo -n $ZLE_VI_MODE_OTH
    fi
}

function zle-backward-delete-char-fix {
    case "$(zle-vi-mode)" in
        $ZLE_VI_MODE_REP)
            if [[ $CURSOR -le $MARK ]]; then
                CURSOR=$(( $(($CURSOR-1)) > 0 ? $(($CURSOR-1)) : 0 ))
                MARK=$CURSOR
            else
                zle undo
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            zle backward-delete-char
            ;;
    esac
}

zle -N zle-backward-delete-char-fix

## Change cursor shape according to the current Vi-mode.
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    case "$(zle-vi-mode)" in
        $ZLE_VI_MODE_CMD) echo -ne '\e[2 q' ;; # cursor -> block
        $ZLE_VI_MODE_INS) echo -ne '\e[6 q' ;; # cursor -> vertical bar
        $ZLE_VI_MODE_REP)
            echo -ne '\e[4 q' # cursor -> underline
            MARK=$CURSOR
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select

bindkey -v

bindkey '^?' zle-backward-delete-char-fix
bindkey '^h' zle-backward-delete-char-fix
```

The above code will, additionally, cause your cursor shape to change depending on what vi-mode you are currently in (i.e. since this is a copy/paste from my *.zshrc*, and that's what I like). If you don't want this, and just want the plain fix, replace the `zle-init-line` / `zle-keymap-select` function with the following:

```
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    case "$(zle-vi-mode)" in
        $ZLE_VI_MODE_REP)
            MARK=$CURSOR
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
}
```